# Unable to PUT image on Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, amazon-s3

I want to upload a image file (base64) on **amazon S3** but i am continously getting this error :

[image]

I am building an **IONIC app** and my code is :

```
    var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(value);

            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                console.log(this.result);

                // AWS
                AWS.config.update({ 
                    accessKeyId: $rootScope.config.access_key, 
                    secretAccessKey: $rootScope.config.secret_key
                });

                AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';

                var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket:     $rootScope.config.bucket } });

                var params = { 
                    Key: value.name, 
                    ContentType: value.type, 
                    Body: this.result, 
                    ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256',
                    ACL: "public-read"
                };

                bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
                  if(err) {
                    // There Was An Error With Your S3 Config
                    // alert(err.message);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                    return false;
                  }
                  else {
                    // Success!
                    console.log('Upload Done');
                  }
                })
                .on('httpUploadProgress',function(progress) {
                  // Log Progress Information
                  console.log(Math.round(progress.loaded / progress.total * 100) + '% done');
                });
```

Where **value** contains a **dataURI**.

*data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAA.....*
How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

In your Amazon S3 account go to bucket "Properties" -> "Permissions" -> "Edit CORS Configuration"

Set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Origin</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

You can restrict the allowed origin to only your host (e.g. "http://www.example.com" in `<AllowedOrigin>` instead of `*`), but since your bucket is only writable with authentication anyway, this shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a more permissive config to get it to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule> 
</CORSConfiguration>
```